# SQL CASE Query returning Extra record for a Checkbox

Tags: sql, sql-server

THE query returns when checkbox Period Type is clickeed 1 . When no clicked it is 0 . Period Type Property can only store NULL or Current Account Period. 
I need to filter these highlighted rows for both BIT = 1 or 0

```
(
CASE 
    WHEN Period.CheckBoxPeriodType = 1 THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN (Post.ColumnNumber = Thread.ColumnNumber 
                    AND LEN(Thread.AccountPeriodType) > 0 AND  Thread.AccountPeriodType <> '')
                    AND Post.PeriodType = Thread.PeriodType 
            THEN Thread.AccountPeriodType               
            ELSE NULL           
        END
            WHEN Post.CheckBoxPeriodType = 0 AND  THEN ''
            WHEN Post.CheckBoxPeriodType IS NULL THEN cellFormat.AccountPeriodType      

        END  
     ) as MyCaseStatement
```

[image]

Comment: sorry its my first time dont know how to indent it in here

Comment: `Current Account Period` is a string?

Comment: Yes Periodtype (NvarChar(64), Null )

Comment: Yes CurrenAccountPeriod is a string type

Comment: Did you tried coalesce (= isnull())?

Comment: Sorry where should i use the coalese ?

Comment: pick either mysql or sql-server please